# Trouble with my property using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am having trouble with my property always being null in my app, but I believe that the problem may be deeper than that.  The requirement is to have a data layer class that contains my connection string to my access database.  This calls another class which pulls the database information and sets it back to the data layer class.  I must then use ONLY the data layer class to get my records.  The problem is that my property is always null.  Here is the code for the data layer class:

```
{
class CustomerDL
{

    OleDbConnection aConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=CIS3341.accdb;");
    string names;
    public void initializeConnection() 
    {
        Customer.initializeConnection(aConnection); 
    }


    public string getNames
    {
        get { return names; }
        set { names = value; }
    }

}
```

}

And here is the other class:

```
 class Customer
{

    static OleDbConnection aConnection = null;
    string names;

    public static void initializeConnection(OleDbConnection aDbConnection)
    {

        aConnection = aDbConnection;
        aConnection.Open();
        getNames();
    }
    public static void getNames()
    {
        CustomerDL aCustomer = new CustomerDL();
        OleDbDataAdapter myAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        if (aConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            aConnection.Open();
        }
        OleDbCommand cmd = aConnection.CreateCommand();
        OleDbDataReader dbReader = null;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CustomerName FROM Customer";
        dbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dbReader.Read())
        {
            aCustomer.getNames +=  (string)dbReader["CustomerName"].ToString() + "\r\n";
        }

        dbReader.Close();
        //return aCustomer ;


    }

}
```

Now when i use this code on my form:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form

{
    CustomerDL customer = new CustomerDL();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        customer.initializeConnection();
        string fast = customer.getNames;
        richTextBox1.Text = fast;
    }
```

customer.getNames; is always null.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't assigning anything to the proper instance of `CustomerDL`.

Comment: I'm sorry could you elaborate and maybe provide a sample.  I'm a little confused.

Comment: I guess Daniel is talking about that you create a new `CustomerDL` in `Customer.getNames(...)` instead of passing the existing instance as a parameter from `CustomerDL.initializeConnection()`.

Comment: @Albin:  I dont know what you mean by existing instance.  I'm still a little new at this.

Comment: @broke: Have a look. When you create a new `Form1`, a new `CustomerDL` is created by the line `CustomerDL customer = new CustomerDL();`. Let's call this `CustomerDL` as `c1`. In the constructor of the `Form1` you call `customer.initializeConnection();`, this executes `initializeConnection()` on `c1`. Inside of that `initializeConnection()` you call a static method `initializeConnection()` of the class `Customer`. There you call static `getNames()`, which creates a **new** `CustomerDL`, which have nothing to do with `c1`. Let's call it `c2`. (to be continued)

Comment: (continued) Then you modify the value of `getNames` on `c2`, but these changes don't touch `c1` at all! After the end of static `getNames()` from `Customer` (not `CustomerDL`) the `c2` is lost, and the `c1` is not updated at all. So the property `getNames` in `c1` will never be actually touched.

Comment: @Vlad: I see what the problem is now, i just dont know how to fix it since i have to follow those guidelines which confuse me even more.

Comment: Basically, I would merge the classes `Customer` and `CustomerDL` together as the first idea. What are the guidelines which you mentioned?

Comment: Well i have to have two classes.  A data layer and a problem domain layer.  The data layer must pass the connection string to he PDL.  The PDL must handle the connection string and select the records from the database.  The PDL must then send the information back to the data layer.  So the goal is to call the data layer class only.  in Form1.

Answer (score 1):

`customer.getNames` never gets accessed whatsoever. You are initializing your connection, but in that method you use a new `CustomerDL`: `CustomerDL aCustomer = new CustomerDL();`. You have to provide that instance to the static method for it to do something.

Comment: I'm sorry could you elaborate and maybe provide a sample. I'm a little confused

Answer (score 1):

in `CustomerDL` the member `names` has the default value null, you can initialize it with  `string names = string.Empty;`

Answer (score 1):

You really should consolidate the Customer and CustomerDL classes into one class.  There is too much duplication.  So instead of having CustomerDL call Customer, just put the getnames() code in your CustomerDL class.  And scrap all the static modifiers.  By your form example, you are instantiating CustomerDL and calling methods on it.  Make the class and its methods non-static, and this will work much better for you.

Comment: This is how i would have done it too, but this is a homework assignment and i have to follow specific guidelines.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post the parameters for the assignment.  Like, what do you have to start with a class the teacher pre-defined for you, or can you create your own.  If so, what is the original code for the class.  If not, what exactly are the written requirements?

Comment: Yes this code is based off a class the teacher pre - defined for us.  I had to modify it for my program, but i have to have 2 classes and only be able to call one.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems that is preventing you from figuring this one out is your naming conventions...

- You have both properties and methods named the same (I would leave the word "get" off of properties).
- You have a "CustomerDL" object that you named "customer". The problem is you also have a "Customer" class.
- You have a static method coded to do what you want, but you are never calling it.

IMHO if you take a little more care in your naming conventions, it will be a lot easier to troubleshoot these kinds of issues....There are a few things wrong with the code, but I quickly gave fixing it a shot. Hope it helps:

```
class CustomerDL   
{ 
    OleDbConnection aConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=CIS3341.accdb;");   

    public string GetNames()
    {
        string NamesToReturn = ""; 

        try 
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter myAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();     
            if (aConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)     
            {     
                aConnection.Open();     
            }     

            OleDbCommand cmd = aConnection.CreateCommand();     
            OleDbDataReader dbReader = null;     

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CustomerName FROM Customer";    

            dbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();     

            while (dbReader.Read())     
            {     
                NamesToReturn +=  (string)dbReader["CustomerName"].ToString() + "\r\n";     
            }     

            dbReader.Close();

        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            aConnection.Close(); //makes sure it closes...
        }   


        return NamesToReturn;
     }     

}
```

Then you can do this:

```
class Customer              
{         

    private CustomerDL customerData = new CustomerDL(); 

    public string Names { get; set; }            

    public string FillNames()
    {
        this.Names = customerData.GetNames();
    }  
}
```

```
public partial class Form1 : Form                    
{             
    Customer customer = new Customer();             
    public Form1()             
    {             
        InitializeComponent(); 

        customer.FillNames();
        richTextBox1.Text = customer.Names;                        
    }   
 }
```

Note: This code is very crude and I have not double checked it, but I beleive it will get you pointed in the right direction.